# Scrolling Activity with circular profile image view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating an android scrolling activity for profile, i want the scrolling activity to include a circular image view for user's profile and make it hide and collapse with the action bar, when the page is scrolled.

I have created the scrolling activity which includes: coordinateLayout, AppBarLayout, CollapsingToolBarLayout, the circularImageView, the FAB and a nestedScrollView..
It works fine, but the circularImageView stays on top regardless of the scroll, i just want it to collapse with the actionbar the same way the FAB disappears on scroll up. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ProfileActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/profile_toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/place_image"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/zeal"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/profile_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="124dp"
            android:layout_height="124dp"
            android:src="@drawable/wale"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/profile_app_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
            />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/profile_app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_profile" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I just want it to collapse with the actionbar the same way the FAB disappears on scroll up. Thanks.

Comment: Please, share your xml layout.

Comment: i have shared it sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FloatingActionButton` is specially designed to be used with a`CollapsingToolBar` but `CircularImageView` is not. For this reason, this object does not disappear when the toolbar is collapsed.

However, you can do it programmatically.

```
    circleImageView = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.profile_app_bar); // get the AppBarLayout
    // create a Listener to detect collapse
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if ( verticalOffset < -26) { // change this value to match your needs
                // Collapsed
                circleImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // Expanded
                circleImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Of course, you can use a shrink animation to match the same effect as a `FloatingActionButton`.

**EDIT**

Shrinking animation

Create a new xml file in res/anim

shrink.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:toXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toYScale="0"
        android:duration="5000"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" >
    </scale>

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"
        android:duration="5000" >
    </alpha>
</set>
```

Create a global variable called `boolean collapsed;`

Use like this:

```
    appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.profile_app_bar);
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if ( verticalOffset < -26) {
                if (!collaped) {
                    circleImageView.animate().scaleX(0f).scaleY(0f).setDuration(200).start();
                    collapsed = true;
                }

            } else {
                if (collapsed) {
                    circleImageView.animate().scaleX(1).scaleY(1f).setDuration(200).start();
                    collapsed = false;
                }


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It works thanks, can you provide a link where i can learn the shrinking animation?